# arabic Wordpress website using woo commerce public pages appears in english not in arabic

Tags: wordpress, translation, woocommerce, arabic, public

I'm building Arabic only website, I'm using the woocommerce, i added the Arabic mo and po files to the woo commerce plugin, and the translation working good in the wp admin pages, but it's not working in the public pages the English language keeps appearing.

I tried other languages like french it works fine for both admin and public pages.

Is it because the Arabic is RTL language or it's something else, any one know what is the problem???

My site: `www.yasmeenart.com`

Comment: Which wordpress plugin are you using for translation, [WPML](http://wpml.org/) or  [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/)?

Answer (score 0):

does your file 
wp-config.php
have this line ?

```
define ('WPLANG', 'ar');
```

also when you upload your .po and .mo files to woocommerce, files should be this name:
woocommerce-ar.mo
woocommerce-ar.po